# Is it possible to create heatmap from layers of polygon geometry type?

Tags: qgis, geometry, heat-map

I'm new to GIS and my question is whether I can create a heatmap from a layer with polygon (multipolygon) geometry. As far as I know, it is only possible to create a heatmap from layers with point and line geometry. If this is the case, is there any way to export the data to a layer with point geometry without creating e.g. a CSV file with the coordinates?

Comment: I've split a polygon into the outline line and a MultiPoint union of the centroids of tessellated hexagons overlaid on the polygon which were also inside a negative buffer of the polygon. The distance between the centroids was influenced by the heatmap decay distance.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you want the heatmap to look like.

If you want areas where the polygons overlap to be brighter depending on how many polygons overlap that area, you can achieve that using transparency and/or blending modes. In the last two images below, notice that the polygons are darker in areas where they overlap. This is not really a heatmap, but it may achieve the same need.

Overlapping polygons with default style:

[image]

Overlapping polygons with feature blending mode, "multiply":

[image]

Overlapping polygons with 50% opacity:

[image]

Otherwise, create a grid of evenly spaced points inside each polygon, then create a normal heatmap from that point layer.

To create a grid of points inside each polygon:

1. Use the `create grid` tool to create a point grid over the entire extent of your polygon layer. The grid spacing should be small enough that each polygon has multiple points in it; finding the right spacing may take some trial and error. (The grid spacing is too large in my example.)

   [image]

   [image]
2. Take the `intersection` of the polygon and grid layers, using the grid as the input layer and the polygons as the overlay layer.

   [image]

   [image]

   If you use the Intersect tool on a point in an area where the polygons overlap, you will see that there are as many copies of that point as there are overlapping polygons.

   [image]
3. Create a heatmap of the intersection point layer, using either the heatmap style option or the `Heatmap (Kernal Density Estimation)` tool.

   [image]

   Here's the same heatmap overlaid on the original polygons:

   [image]